# How to modularize GraphQL schema when using `buildSchema`?

Tags: graphql

It has been about a year since I updated my graphql-js dependency. I see now that there is a utility that simplifies schema generation: `buildSchema`. This function takes, as an arg, your entire schema, as a string, in the GraphQL language. That's awesome, but is there a way to modularize this? My schema is not super small, and would suck to cram into a single `.graphql` file. Is there some sort of utility or pattern for storing each type definition in its own file, for example?

Comment: I wrote a library that can do this https://github.com/graphql-factory/graphql-factory

Comment: Here is an article on the best way to do this if you're using Apollo's graphql-tools: https://hackernoon.com/graphql-schemas-easier-better-structure-31677a640d18

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the `graphql-tools` package, you can use `makeExecutableSchema` to modularize your schema like so:

```
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs: [schema1, schema2, schema3, ...],
    resolvers: resolvers,
});
```

That way each type can be defined in its own file.

Comment: Here are the docs: http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/graphql-tools/generate-schema.html#modularizing

Answer (score 0):

You can further improve your schema modularity by using `merge-graphql-schemas` package.

Here is a modular graphql server seed - [graphql-server-seed](https://github.com/tomyitav/graphql-server-seed)

The project structure allows you to separate your types and resolver to multiple files. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apollo's graphql-tools, then I've found that the best way to structure your schema is to use [schemaglue.js](https://github.com/nicolasdao/schemaglue) (disclaimer: I've built this):

```
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require('graphql-tools')
const { glue } = require('schemaglue')

const { schema, resolver } = glue('src/graphql')

const executableSchema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs: schema,
    resolvers: resolver
})
```

And then you'll be able to structure your schema and resolvers with something similar to this:

```
- src/
   |__ graphql/
          |__ product/
          |       |__ schema.js
          |       |__ resolver.js
          |
          |__ variant/
                  |__ schema.js
                  |__ resolver.js

- index.js
- package.json
```

I've written a detailed article about this [here](https://hackernoon.com/graphql-schemas-easier-better-structure-31677a640d18).